# Creating SignInScreen which leads to HomeScreen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Hey im trying to learn React Native.

I found some nice tutorials to create my app. So far did I manage to program a form with firebase authentication. After login the user is directed to the mainscreen.To do that I used the StackNavigator. Now I wanted that the mainscreen had a BottomTabNavigator to switch between pages. It also should have a sign out button to redirect back to the signInScreen. but how can I do this without the BottomTabNavigator and the StackNavigator interfering with each other? Because it is like having two different hierarchies.

**App.js**

```
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="SignInScreen" component={SignInScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

export default App;
```

**SignInScreen.js**

```
const SignInScreen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        navigation.replace("Main");
      }
    })

    return unsubscribe
  }, [])


  const handleSignUp = () => {
    auth
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(userCredentials => {
        const user = userCredentials.user; console.log(user.mail);
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error.message));
  }

  const handleLogin = () => {
    auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(userCredentials => {
        const user = userCredentials.user;
        console.log(user.mail)
      })
      .catch(error => alert(error.message));
  }

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container}>

      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput placeholder="Email" value={email} onChangeText={text => setEmail(text)}  style={styles.input} />
        <TextInput placeholder="Password" value={password} onChangeText={text => setPassword(text)}  style={styles.input} secureTextEntry/>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLogin} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Login</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSignUp} style={[styles.button, styles.buttonOutline]}>
          <Text style={styles.buttonOutlineText}>Register</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};
```

I've been dealing with this problem for several hours. I hope someone can help me :D

Answer (score 0):

There is a standard pattern to deal with this kind of problem. It is described [here in the documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/). In short, we create a context and use conditional rendering for the two screens, thus we do not need to use navigation at all.

Here is an example based on your current implementation.

```js
const SignInContext = React.createContext();

const App = () => {

   const [isSignedIn, setIsSignedIn] = useState(false)
   const signInContextValue = useMemo(() => ({
       isSignedIn,
       setIsSignedIn
   }), [isSignedIn])


   return (
    <SignInContext.Provider value={signInContextValue}>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {!isSignedIn ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="SignInScreen" component={SignInScreen} />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainScreen} />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </SignInContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Initially, the `SignInScreen` will be rendered. Here is the how to use the context in that screen.

```js
const SignInScreen = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  
  const { setIsSignedIn } = React.useContext(SignInContext);


  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        setIsSignedIn(true)
      }
    })

    return unsubscribe
  }, [])

  ...

  return (...)
}
```

For your sign out button you do this similarly. Reference the context via `React.useContext(SignInContext)` and set it back to false.

Comment: Hey after implementing the changes in the SingInScreen I get some errors. It says it couldn't find the SignInContext variable. So tried: import { SignInContext } from '../App.js'; but that just gave me: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Context._context'). What should I do? :3 :)

Comment: Export the `SignInContext` via `export const SignInContext = React.createContext()`

Comment: Than import it as you did

Comment: Thanks man you really helping me out here! Now I face a bug. The button (with the onPress(handleSignOut)) doesnt respond anymore. I put this in the file where the button is: `const { setIsSignedIn } = React.useContext(SignInContext);

const handleSignOut = () => {
    auth
    .signOut()
    .then(() => { setIsSignedIn(false)
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error))
  }`

Comment: Im pretty new at React so im sorry that i dont get it D:

Comment: Can you share the whole component of your signout button?

Comment: `const MainScreen = ({}) => {

const navigation = useNavigation();

const { setIsSignedIn } = React.useContext(SignInContext);

const handleSignOut = () => {
    auth
    .signOut()
    .then(() => { setIsSignedIn(false)
    })
    .catch(error => alert(error))
  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>MAIN</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleSignOut} style={styles.button}>
        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>SignOut</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );

}

export default MainScreen;`

Comment: Hmm this should work. Can you console.log the signIn state in App and see if it changes if you press the button?

Comment: I did try console.log with the signOut button and saw that it printed something right after i started the debug. And dont hear the click sound nor see a darker transition in the Android simulator. So its like the button became a div. And since I successfully logged in for the first time, it brings me immediately in the Mainscreen. (Not like an instant. I saw the transition animation)

Comment: Ok for some reason the button works again... I did literally  nothing. O_O Anyways thank you so much for your help and patience!